# Github. An authentication error occurred. We could not sync with the server

Tags: macos, github, synchronization, github-for-mac

I am using [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/).

Now If I try to perform `Sync`, I got the following message:

```
An authentication error occurred. We could not sync with the server.
```

If I go to the following page https://github.com/settings/ssh/audit
I get the following message:

```
All your SSH Keys have been verified.
```

What can I do to fix this problem?

P.S.
I have already followed the following steps with no success:
http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set the remote repo correctelly?

```
Settings -> Primary remote repository (origin)
```

Paste your project's repo address (e.g. `git@github.com:username/your_proj.git`) to there.